# MVVM Light 4 RTM: Where are the templates?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm-light

When I have installed the *MVVM Light v3.xx* in *Visual Studio 2010* I have many templates for creating MVVM projects.

But I need to do a clean install of *Visual Studio*, and in this ocasion I have installed the version *4 RTM* of *MVVM Light*, and I don't see any templates.

I notice that in the install wizard, There is templates for express edition of *Visual Studio*, but no to the Profesional Edition.

Is there no template in the new version of MVVM light?

Comment: Can you try running devenv /resetuserdata & devenv /setup to see if it is just not getting placed in your user hive?

Answer (score 2):

v4 of MVVM Light changed to using a VSIX to install the templates. Just run `C:/Program Files (x86)/Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)/Mvvm Light Toolkit/VSIX/MvvmLight.VS2010.vsix` and you should have the templates.

Also make sure you downloaded from this link: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/downloads/get/476364 (I think there is a VS2012-only installer as well)

Comment: Your first hint got me there. In that folder were VS2012 files. I don't know why. I installed both Toolkits trying to make it work. Maybe because of this. I will write up an own answer but the bounty will go to you.

Answer (score -1):

I had Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 installed and maybe that was the problem. But I am not sure.

This is how I got it to work:

1. Deinstall Visual Studio 2012
2. Deinstall MVVM Toolkit
3. Install MVVM Toolkit 4.0 (for VS2010)
4. Execute `C:\Program Files (x86)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Vsix\MvvmLight.VS2010.vsix`

After that the templates were installed in VS2010.

Maybe it will be enough if you just execute the file in `4.` (if the VS2010 file is there) like in @RandomEngy's answer suggested.